# Legend not corresponding to colours on the Map. Fusion Tables

Tags: javascript, css, google-fusion-tables

I am using the fusion tables API to style maps. However in the legend, some countries (Uganda and Mozambique) are not showing the correct colours displayed in the legend.

[Link to the map](http://andrew-molo.com/test/)

Here is the code for displaying the legend

```
    <style type="text/css">
  #legend {
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 150px;
  }

  #legend p {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 3px;
  }

  #legend div {
    clear: both;
  }

  .color {
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
  }
    #map-canvas{

        width: 700px;
        height: 650px;

    }
</style>
```

Code fot displaying the map

```
function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-2.358937, 27.618881),
      zoom: 4,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      query: {
        select: 'geometry',
        from: '1MXudMo9A8yUjpO89hkac74LzGEKPyA_tDzkWJ3hl'
      }
    });
    layer.setMap(map);

    initSelectmenu();
    for (column in COLUMN_STYLES) {
      break;
    }
    applyStyle(map, layer, column);
    addLegend(map);

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('selector'),
        'change', function() {
          var selectedColumn = this.value;
          applyStyle(map, layer, selectedColumn);
          updateLegend(selectedColumn);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The column `'Total No of Points'` has been set to the type `Text`, the comparison will be based on strings what will  not give the expected results.

Simple test:

```
alert('9'>'10');//true
alert(9>10);//false
```

**Solution:** set the type of the column to `Number`